# how to read connection string using configuration in .NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm migrating my code from .NET CORE 2.2 to .NET CORE 3.1. I'm encountering the below error while reading connection string from appsettings.json

"'Configuration' does not contain a definition for 'GetConnectionString'"

I'm using the below code in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

My appsettings.json is as below

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=abc.net;Initial Catalog=xyz;User ID=paper;Password=pencil"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "serverSigningPassword": "key",
  "accessTokenDurationInMinutes": 2
}
```

Is there any way to read this connection string and other variables in appsettings.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things to be noted,

Have you injected in the constructor?

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

and use it as

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
     services.AddDbContext<ShelterPZ_DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
  }
```